# Music player with seek function from command line

Tags: command-line, flac, music-player

Popular Linux music players (Audacious, cmus...) don't have a seek function that can be invoked from command line. Is there any player with such a function to play FLAC format from a start time to an end time? It should allow something like `$ player --from 1:00 --to 2:00 sample.flac` so `sample.flac` plays from time 1:00 to 2:00.

Answer (score 0):

VLC can do it like this:

```
$ cvlc song.flac --start-time=10 --stop-time=12.5
```

see [manual](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Jump_to_a_certain_time/).

Comment: Note that just many players can do that : mpv --start=X --end=Y <file-name> and of course mplayer via its -ss and -endpos parameter.